# Linear matrix transformation that keeps the first nonzero element in each row of a matrix and zeros the rest

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, linear-transformations

I need to find a matrix transformation that takes a (non-square) matrix and within each of its rows keeps the **first** nonzero element in that row and zeros out the rest of the entries within that row.

I tried to solve the linear matrix equation AX = B to get the matrix transformation A as A = B X^T (XX^T)^{-1} , where X is the matrix to be transformed as such, and B is the desired output matrix (X with only its first nonzero element in each row) but I look for a more straightforward and possibly more elegant way to do it. I appreciate creative answers!

Thanks!

Comment: If you literally mean that it should keep the first *nonzero* element in each row, then that transformation is not a linear one. If you mean instead that it should preserve the first entry in each row (regardless of whether that entry is zero or not), then that will be a linear transformation.